# telegram-cli: How to download and show images?

Tags: telegram

I'm using the telegram-cli commandline client on Ubuntu, my Ubuntu phone and on my FreeBSD desktops. Works very fine. I do not unterstand how to download and view images others sent me. The help does not say much about. It points to the syntax with some 'msg-id', what could be this?

For example, if someone sends me a image it says:

```
[22:14]  Lina  »»» [image 32.webp: type=image/webp size=336x512 size=28KiB]
```

How can I access this image?

Answer (score 4):

You can see this line in `help` of `telegram-cli`.

```
view_photo <msg-id>     Downloads file to downloads dirs. Then tries to open it with system default action
```

That says, you should enter `msg-id` as an argument to `view_photo`.

For knowing `msg-id` of a message, you should use `-N` or `--enable-msg-id` arguments.

For example you should run `telegram-cli` with this command:

```
telegram-cli --enable-msg-id
```

And you can see a number before your message. That number is your message id. For example:

```
12 [22:14]  Lina  »»» [image 32.webp: type=image/webp size=336x512 size=28KiB]
```

Here your `msg-id` is 12, So for show that image you can use this command:

```
view_photo 12
```

---

But this is not really a photo, its Stickers of Telegram (Because of its `.webp` format).

For see this type of image you can use `imagemagick` with `webp` package.

```
sudo apt install imagemagick webp
```

So you can use `view_photo <msg-id>` command in telegram-cli, and then choose `imagemagick` from applications list. That image should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The information of ali76 contains the missing link, the piece of information I missed. I saw already in the help, that I have to use a msg_id and how to enable this, but did not know which number of the chat line it was, i.e. this is missing in the help. Having this clear now, I debugged it in my desktop:

1. telegram-cli downloads the file to ~/.telegram-cli/downloads
2. starts /usr/local/bin/xdg-open filename (a simple shell script)
3. this in turn starts /usr/local/bin/kde-open filename

The latter knows how to open certain image types, for *.webp I used /usr/local/bin/display (from the ImageMagick suite) and let kde-open remember this selection for this type of file.

Comment: Hi guru; I says that the number before that line is the msg-id for example in `1234 [22:14]  Lina  »»» [image 32.webp: type=image/webp size=336x512 size=28KiB] ` , 1234 is your msg-id . And you can see this image with `view_photo` and no need to goes to `~/.telegram-cli/downloads` directory.